# How to make webpack prefer file with extension?

Tags: typescript, webpack, sass

I have two files:

```
- somefile.scss
- somefile.scss.ts
```

in the source code, the file is consumed like this (from a typescript file):

```
import styles from "somefile.scss"
```

The typescript works properly and importing the correct file (.scss.ts), but webpack picks the wrong one (.scss)

How can I make webpack prefer `.scss.ts` file over `.scss` (given both exist in the same directory, and I cannot change the names or the directory)?

I have tried to modify the resolve (without success):

```js
// not working
resolve: {
  extensions: [".scss.ts", ".ts"]
}
```

```js
// also not working
resolve: {
  extensions: ["*", ".ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the most readable and clear way is just to import the file with its full name:

```js
import styles from "somefile.scss.ts"
```

That way you don't have to guess wich one is going to be imported and if someone changes `resolve` webpack configuration later the build most likely won't get affected.

And if you really want to lay it on `resolve.extenstions` option you should write it as:

```js
    ...
    resolve: {
        // the last `...` is optional in case you want 
        // to keep the default webpack extension resolution
        extensions: [".ts", "", "..."]
    }
    ...
```

Comment: The webpack gives an error: configuration.resolve.extensions[1] should be an non-empty string. Empty strings seem to be prohibited now in webpack config. I cann't change the import unfortunately, that is generated by a third-party tool I cannot modify

Comment: Your webpack config is in the '.ts' file?

Comment: In fact webpack@5 is pretty much ok with empty strings in the extensions array. Though the typings may be not.

Comment: yes, webpack5, and the config is in .ts file - thank you I'll try to resolve by moving to .js

Comment: You may just annotate it with `@ts-nocheck` directive

Comment: Sorry for confusion -it's not webpack, webpack config is plan js. It's gulpfile that its typescript. And it's not a typescript error, it's a runtime error: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.  - configuration.resolve.extensions[1] should be an non-empty string. webpack 5.26

Comment: I don't know how to handle gulpfile config checks. But I've created a sample project to illustrate that the described config works pretty well https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-j3vvbh?file=package.json

Comment: thank you!! Updating webpack from 5.26 to 5.38 solved the issue.